# Bootstrap Date Time Picker Gap between the calendar icon and the text field

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

In my date time picker i have a gap as seen in the picture how can i fix this? I am using .Net MVC. With bootstrap v3.3.7 and  Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS 4.17.45.

Image of the gap:

[image]

Here is the BundleConfig.cs

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/lib").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js",
                    "~/Scripts/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
                     "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                     "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootbox.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));



        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-custom.css",
                  "~/Content/datatables/css/datatables.bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Here is the _layout.cshtml

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
```

Here is the DatePicker HTML in the view

```
<div class="container">
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-4'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the script in the view

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
 });
```

Thanks in advance.
Edit: I have forgotten to note that the click on the calendar icon works and the pop-up dialog is properly formatted.
Edit2: Here is the link to the css.

https://bootswatch.com/3/united/bootstrap.css

Something funny is going on when I remove the renders from the _layout.cshtml and insert the fallowing they appear fine. I am puzzled does any one have an idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.css" />
```

Comment: Do you have a CSS file you can also post?

Comment: I have posted it

Comment: When I comment site.css from bundle config the gap dissapears. When I delete the contents of site.css the gap is still there. Again not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You haven't provided the CSS, you've provided the tags for the CSS files. Your best option is to reproduce the code in a fiddle with all the appropriate CSS links/files, so someone could look at it and inspect the code. Otherwise it's asking us to make guesses.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default `Site.css` automatically added to the styling in Visual Studio, remove:

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

from that css file, because setting the max-width of the input is conflicting with (overriding) the bootstrap css. Probably better still, remove the `Site.css` file altogether to avoid other conflicts.

Comment: When I just remove those lines the gap is still there. Heck even when I delete the contents of the whole file the gap is still there. As long as there is a reference to site.css the gap stays.

Comment: Remove all references to Site.css (including any bundling), rebuild the application and refresh the page using shift+f5 to reload the page and clear out the browser cache (check out stackoverflow.com/a/20569488/5957979 for other ways if that doesn't work). If that doesn't work, use the browser's inspector to see if there is any other css impacting on those elements that is in conflict.